# Change orientation without loading again

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to change the orientation, but i have two different xml, one for portrait and the other one for landscape. The same information appear in the screen, except that it's moved to use some space. If i do :

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

It will only change from portrait to landscape in the same xml.

How can i change that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `onConfigurationChanged()` method in your activity. Check the current orientation and set appropriate content view using `setContentView()`.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.getConfiguration() == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(landscape_layout);
    } else {
        setContentView(portrait_layout);
    }
    initViews();
}
```

Comment: code like finding and initiating the views. Mostly the stuff you do in onCreate.

Comment: -1 this is unnecessary ... Android already does this without additional overrides.  See @CommonsWare answer for the default behaviour using layout-land and layout-port resource folders

Answer (score 1):

Set your view as a class variable:

```
private TextView yourView;
```

Add the following to the `onCreate()` method:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

And add an override on the saving of the instance state to save the state

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    yourView.saveState(outState);
}
```

Finally:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

You should be able to manage config changes with this...

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity, override this method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

}
```

This will be triggered when orientation is changed. You can find out in what orientation you are using the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how android works. If you want a different layout for portrait/landscape you must let the system handle the configuration change for you and load the appropriate layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
```

It solves mine and your problem :)